# Stay highlighted the selected item in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I manually made navigation drawer using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and `DrawerLayout`, now I want selected item to stay highlighted, either when I open the drawer or close it selected item(fragment) should be highlighted using some color. I have a `ListView` in my drawer.
This is drawer.xml (fragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#34344d"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist_1"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="#fffff7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_view_scolor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have listSelector file which is list_view_scolor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
      <!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_listselector" />    
      <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_listselector" />
<!-- Pressed -->
<item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_listselector" />
</selector>
```

I have list_view_listselector.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/pressed_color" />

</shape>
```

I have not posted code of single_row, if you need to see this file, I can update that. Please comment if required.

BaseAdapter for listview :-

```
public class ListView_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ListView_Adapter(Context context , String[] list ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        view=   inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_row_listview, null);

        TextView drawer_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_item);
        String item = list[position];
        drawer_item.setText(item);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "robot_condensed_light.ttf");
        drawer_item.setTypeface(type);
    /*  if(position==0){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(context.getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_1)));
        }
        else if(position == 1){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(context.getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_2)));
        }
        else if(position == 2){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(context.getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_3)));
        }
        else if(position == 3){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(context.getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_4)));
        }
        else if(position == 4){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(context.getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_5)));
        }*/
        return view;
    }


}
```

This is implementation of how i navigate through fragments

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist_1);
        ListView_Adapter adapter1 = new ListView_Adapter(this, item1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
        Fragment_Home frag = new Fragment_Home();
        fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, frag).commit();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
                //v.setSelection(position);
                lv.setSelected(true);
                Fragment frag;
                if (position == 0) {
                    // getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new
                    // ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.string.color_list_2)));
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                    frag = new Fragment_Home();
                    fragManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, frag).commit();
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    // getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new
                    // ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_2))));
                    frag = new Fragment_PaytmWallet();
                    fragManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, frag).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PayTM Wallet");
                    // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
                    // Window window = getWindow();
                    // window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    // window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                    // window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_primary_2)));
                    // }
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    // getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new
                    // ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_3))));
                    frag = new Fragment_Categories();
                    fragManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, frag).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Categories");
                    // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
                    // Window window = getWindow();
                    // window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    // window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_primary_3)));
                    // }
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    // getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new
                    // ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_4))));
                    frag = new Fragment_AskAQues();
                    fragManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, frag).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ask a Question");
                    // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
                    // Window window = getWindow();
                    // window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    // window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_primary_4)));
                    // }
                } else if (position == 4) {
                    // getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new
                    // ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_5))));
                    frag = new Fragment_BeAnExpert();
                    fragManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, frag).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Be an Expert");
                    // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
                    // Window window = getWindow();
                    // window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    // window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.color_list_primary_5)));
                    // }
                }

                dl.closeDrawers();

            }
        });
```

Comment: can you share how you are loading your fragments in navigation drawer ?

Comment: Using FragmentManager , making cases while clicking on listview and instantiating Fragments and then FragmentManager . Should i upload code?

Comment: with the help of adapter right ?

Comment: with the help of base adapter @RaguSwaminathan

Comment: can you please share your adapter and the way you lead the fragments that will be much helpful.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan done

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: did you got it worked?

Comment: Working smooth..  Thanks dude..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

In your adapter create a variable like below and a getter function.

```
int mSelectedItem;

public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
    this.mSelectedItem = selectedItem;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

under your getView method include the below.

```
if (position == mSelectedItem) {
      drawer_item.setTextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_color)); // Highlighting color
    } else {
      drawer_item.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.normal_color)); // normal color
    }
```

In your mainactivity call the setSelectedItem by passing the position as like below under onItemclick.

```
adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
```

By now i have changed the highlighted text color. You can follow the same to set it to background. Check if it works for you.